# Center a text box and button perfectly using bootstrap 5

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have the following html using bootstrap 5:

```
<div style="margin-top: 30%" class="text-center">
    
    <h1>Let's get started...</h1>

    <input id="form-input" style="display: inline-block;" type="text" class="form-control mb-3 w-25" placeholder="Search for a prefix" />

    <button id="form-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Find Numbers</button>

</div>
```

This is the result in a browser:

[image]

How can I make sure they are exactly the same height, and if the browser is made too small, the submit button will drop beneath the input

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I did not quite understand your goal, so excuse me if my answer is wrong.
You can user `screen.width` to make the submit button will drop beneath the input.

```
let width = screen.width;
if(width > // any number you want) {
    document.getElementById('form-input').style = 'display: block; margin-left: X px'
}
```

And for the same height you can use `position: relative;` and `position: absolute`:

```
div {
    positon: relative;
}
 
input,
button {
    positon: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want the text box to be the exact same height as the button without making it fixed, so its responsive as so that the button will drop below the text box if the window gets too small

Comment: You can just change it with @media

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap them with flex parent like this:

```
<div style="margin-top: 30%" class="text-center">
<h1>Let's get started...</h1>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap">
  <input id="form-input" style="display: inline-block;" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for a prefix" />
  <button id="form-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Find Numbers</button>
</div>
```

and adjust the width for the small screen (I'd suggest using col-lg-* but you are using form-control so it has 100% width):

```
.form-control {
  width: 25%;
}
@media(max-width: 767px) {
  .form-control {
     width: 80%;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```